# use vector of vectors to draw a ground in opengl

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, vector

I initialized the vector as this:

```
   vector<vector<GLfloat> > ground_vertices {
   {-10, -0.1, 50},
   {10, -0.1, 50},
   {-10, -0.1, -300},
   {10, -0.1, -300} };
```

and my drawing function is like this

```
  void Ground() {
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);                
     for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
     {
         glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
         glVertex3f(ground_vertices[i]);
     }
  glEnd();
```

}

But I kept getting

> ground.cpp|37 col 40 error| cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > ::value_type   {aka std::vector}’ to ‘GLfloat {aka float}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void glVertex3f(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)’

I wonder how can I fix it. Thank you!

Comment: using a for loop inside a begin-end block was _never_ a good idea. Not only is this code deprecated since a decade, and totally not functional in modern OpenGL, it also is completely superseded by vertex arrays since _20 years_ now.

Comment: @derhass Hi! Thank you for the comment. What do you suggest to use then?

Comment: [Vertex Buffer Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_buffer_object) and preferably a tutorial for modern OpenGL like [paroj.github.io/gltut/](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/) or [open.gl](http://open.gl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`glVertex3fv(const GLfloat * v)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) and pass a pointer to the vertex data to it.

You can get a pointer to the data contained in a `std::vector` by [`std::vector::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/):

```
glVertex3fv(ground_vertices[i].data());
```

Note, the correct coding with the use of `glVertex3f(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)` would be:

```
glVertex3f(
    ground_vertices[i][0],
    ground_vertices[i][1],
    ground_vertices[i][2]);
```